# Nested for loops in list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm new to python and just trying to learn how to make my code more pythonic.
I'm reading a file into a list of strings and then reading these strings into their own list in python. This is my code.

```
data = [line.strip() for line in open(filename, 'r')]
data = [list(item) for item in data]
```

How can I do this in one line using nested for loops.

Comment: `[list(item) for line in open(filename, 'r') for item in line.strip()]`

Comment: You'll end up with a list of lists. Each inner list will only have one element, that represents a line in the file. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The `for` clauses go in the same order as if you had written a nested loop.

```
data = [list(item) for line in open(filename, 'r') for item in line.strip()]
```

You should be using a `with` statement, though:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = [list(item) for line in f for item in line.strip()]
```